# $\overset r \sum \limits_{k=0}C(m, k)a_k+C(m, k)b_k =C(m, k) \overset r \sum \limits_{k=0}(a_k+b_k)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, field-theory, real-numbers

[image]

Let m, k be integers with $m \ge k$. Then are the below second and third notation equal the first notation? Or can't I use generalized distributive law because the k in C(m, k) ranges from 0 through k-1?

$\overset r \sum \limits_{k=0}(C(m, k)a_k+C(m, k)b_k)$
$=\overset r \sum \limits_{k=0}C(m, k)(a_k+b_k)$
$=C(m, k) \overset r \sum \limits_{k=0}(a_k+b_k)$

[EDIT] parenthesis added in the first notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is correct $\sum_{k=0}^{r} \left(a_k C(m,k) + b_k C(m,k)\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{r} (a_k+b_k) C(m,k)$

As you suspected the second step is incorrect. You can't take $C(m,k)$ out of the summation since $k$ is a variable.

$\sum_{k=0}^{r} a_k C(m,k) \not= C(m,k) \sum_{k=0}^{r} a_k$

Think of it like this - If you have taken $k$ out of the summation then what value will you assign to $C(m,k)$ in $C(m,k) \sum_{k=0}^{r} a_k$?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^ra_kC(m,k)+b_kC(m,k)\ne\sum_{k=0}^r\left[a_kC(m,k)+b_kC(m,k)\right].$ Parentheses are important.